# Is there a better shorthand for Typescript class/interface definitions?

Tags: typescript, class, shorthand

I'm defining a typescript class with constructor parameters defined by an interface, and it **restricts the properties to only those that are defined**.

The following code snippet works as intended, however, is there a way to reduce the code so that it isn't so repetitive? Each property is mentioned 4 times, there must be a better way.

```
interface MyInterface {
  property1: string;
  property2: boolean;
  property3: number;
}
class MyClass {
  property1: string;
  property2: boolean;
  property3: number;
  constructor(parameters: MyInterface) {
    this.property1 = parameters.property1;
    this.property2 = parameters.property2;
    this.property3 = parameters.property3;
  }
}

const example = new MyClass({property1: "Property 1", property2: true, property3: 3, extraProperty: "Shouldn't exist"});
console.log(example);
```

EDIT: I also need to restrict the properties at run-time from objects with additional unknown properties.

Comment: I think the problem you are having is that your example shouldn't compile. You will get a type error because `MyInterface` doesn't have the property `extraProperty`. I'm assuming this object comes from an external API so you can't be sure what properties it will have?

Comment: @GeraintAnderson that's the issue I'm hoping to resolve. I'm needing to take an object from an api and remove the additional undefined properties

Comment: Ahh, that is important information. TypeScript is already restricting properties as much as possible at compile-time. But if you need to check them at run-time with data from API, then you'll need to have actual checks in your code for that, e.g. `if (hasExtraProperties(...)) { throw Error(...) }`

Comment: Or actually you probably want to just ignore the extra properties rather than throwing an error. So maybe just `for (const key in parameters) { if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) { this[key] = parameters[key] } }`

Comment: @MattBrowne I tried that as well, however, this.hasOwnProperty(key) returns false until the property is explicitly set. ie. this.property1 = parameters.property1;

Comment: You'll need a list of keys at runtime of the form `["property1", "property2", "property3"]` in order to do this.  Does something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLREKw) work for you?  Or maybe [this one](https://tsplay.dev/w11blw)?  If so I could write up an answer for your choice; if not could you elaborate on the problem and I can see if it's addressable?

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```js
interface MyInterface {
    property1: string;
    property2: boolean;
    property3: number;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    property1: string;
    property2: boolean;
    property3: number;

    constructor(parameters: MyInterface) {
        Object.assign(this, parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you have the TS `strict` option enabled, you'll need to add `!` to each property declaration to prevent compilation errors (so `property1!: string`, etc.)

Comment: This solution is missing the ability to restrict the properties to only those that are defined. ie. extraProperty: "Shouldn't exist" would be included in the properties, but it shouldn't

Comment: Actually it's still restricting it thanks to the `parameters: MyInterface`. Try it and you'll see that it doesn't let you pass `extraProperty`

Comment: That's true, however, when I'm passing in an object from an external API where the properties are unknown, it returns the extra properties

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but then you need to story class argument in `parameters` property:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  property1: string;
  property2: boolean;
  property3: number;
}
class MyClass {
  constructor(public parameters: MyInterface) {  }
}

const example = new MyClass({ property1: "Property 1", property2: true, property3: 3, extraProperty: "Shouldn't exist" });
console.log(example);

example.parameters.property1 // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkAHKAezOjHQEYAuZAZzClAHMBuE8qmlDoAmZgCNKlADYQ4IXqQrVa6AMzMQAVwC2Y6LwC%20RBFLgsWadAGFT5wnwSUQbKJoRhKUABRlNYqcAI5HBQcNoQkFAszBjYkXgQAJT2pKRgABbALAB0ZCFhEdAWALzBoeGRLHxGRsZObMgQAB5hZDLIpSAQAO6WNmYsXgT8ykIMzABEAAoCKsj0EwA0I4IizOyaEMtKq2rMqsvN7HAzo3STAMrplJpSACYgAORgjU1ZYBPIBom8js7SEGyUkonC8zVaMh%20RCI4O0bUBeXKhSiuVmY3oyAA9JjkJQANZAA)

Please see the `public` keyword I have added in `constructor`

[image]

If you want to validate your object in runtime, you should either use [user-defined-type-guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) or [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts)

TypeScript has static type system

Comment: I'm guessing the OP would prefer not to put all the properties into one `parameters` property. So it would be more like `constructor(public property1: string, public property2: boolean, ...`. The downside is that you'd still have to manually assign each property in the constructor.

Comment: If you use `public` in the constructor you don't need to assign it btw. You're just assigning it to itself.

Comment: @ShamPooSham yeah, so it could just be `constructor(public parameters: MyInterface) { }` (empty constructor body). But if you want to take a `parameters` object as the input and assign it to separate properties (`this.property1`, etc.), you would still need to do assignments.

Comment: @ShamPooSham you are right

Comment: This solution is missing the ability to restrict the properties to only those that are defined. ie. extraProperty: "Shouldn't exist" would be included in the properties, but it shouldn't

Comment: @user10426087 extraProperty is highleted, it means that it is not allowed. I have added a screen shot

Comment: @captain-yossarian the issue I'm having is passing an object at run-time from an external API that has additional properties.

Comment: @user10426087 made an update

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be the most concise way, but not necessarily the best. It depends on your use case—specifically whether or not the `parameters` in the constructor will always match the declared properties of your class. If not, then you would want to stick with using an interface (and using an interface might be cleaner anyway).

```
class MyClass {
    property1!: string
    property2!: boolean
    property3!: number

    constructor(parameters: typeof MyClass.prototype) {
        Object.assign(this, parameters)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MyInterface {
  property1: string;
  property2: boolean;
  property3: number;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  constructor(
    public property1: string,
    public property2: boolean,
    public property3: number
  ) { }
}

const example = new MyClass("Property 1", true, 3, "Shouldn't exist");
console.log(example);
```

By putting `public` in the constructor arguments, I don't need to declare them outside of the constructor. `MyClass` implements `MyInterface` so that I know I have declared all properties I need in `MyClass`.

Maybe this doesn't really apply to your needs since you'll have to manually assign each property in the constructor, but it might give you something to think about.